# What is the cheapest cloud non-BLOB storage?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, cloud, storage, azure-storage

I have an iPhone app that must use external cloud db to sync data between users. Data is structured, so BLOB storage will not do.
So far the only alternatives that i see are

- Amazon SimpleDB
- MS Azure Storage (Tables). I didnt get if i could use just Storage and no Azure instances.

Are there any other similar providers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely use Azure Storage (which includes tables, blobs, and queues) with no compute instances. Storage costs <strike>$0.15 / GB</strike> $0.11 or less / GB depending on quantity, and you'll pay for bandwidth usage (<strike>$0.10</strike> free inbound, <strike>$0.15</strike> $0.12 / GB outbound). And you'll pay $0.01 / <strike>10,000</strike> 100,000 storage transactions.

Regarding Azure tables specifically, you can have as many tables as you'd like within your storage account. Tables are schema-less, with up to 100TB per storage account.

You can find more pricing info [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/).

You can sign up for a 90-day trial, including storage, [here](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/).

Comment: Unfortunately, as i found out, Azure is not available in Russia (that's where i live) yet. So I'll wait then or will go with some fake account, if it takes too long.